# Equal sign and semicolons in Spring path variable

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have rest controller with path like: `"/abc/{variable}"`

```
    @GetMapping(produces = "application/json", value = "/abc/{variable}")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public List<String[]> controller(@PathVariable String variable) {
        //code
    }
```

I would like to pass string with multiple semicolons and equal sign with request like :

> {host}/abc/xyz=123;xyz

and get full string `xyz=123;xyz;` in path variable of controller method.

I have configured Spring to not remove semicolons like this:

```
    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();
        urlPathHelper.setRemoveSemicolonContent(false);
        configurer.setUrlPathHelper(urlPathHelper);
    }
```

But the result is truncated to `xyz=123` in this example. (possibly because of how matrix variables work in Spring).
Is it possible to use path variable with multiple semicolons and equal signs in Spring and capture complete string?

Comment: Have you looked into `@MatrixVariable`? I think the first value is just being captured as the path parameter.

Comment: I want to capture complete string not just first value.

Comment: Then provide a map for all the values, per the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/MatrixVariable.html

Comment: Could you give an example url of request you want to perform?

Comment: I am using only one equal sign with multiple semicolons so i don't have map for all values.

Comment: Url is: {host}/abc/xyz=123;xyz;

Comment: I tried this and able to see the value `xyz=123;xyz;` in controller. I didn't even override PathMatchConfigurer. Are you sure this is a problem?

Comment: In controller, do you mean in path variable ? I have deleted PathMatchConfigurer and it didn't help.

Comment: @Radek23445 Yes in path variable, what is your raw request? Can you also include that in the question?

Comment: I have added request to post. What Spring version did you use ?
I have used Spring Boot 2.1.1

Comment: Spring boot 2.1.8, I don't think it's due to version, what is your rest api testing tool? Postman? SoapUi? curl?

Comment: I am testing it with browser.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206598/discussion-between-prakashb-and-radek23445).

Comment: Try `@GetMapping(produces = "application/json", value = "/abc/{variable:.+}")`

Answer (score 0):

Since `;` (as well as `=`) is a [special character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) you have to encode it before sending the URL to the server. After encoding your URL turns to:

`{host}/abc/xyz%3D123%3Bxyz`

Spring provides utility class `UriUtils` for encoding/decoding operations. So if you compose URL on the server side you can use `UriUtils.encodePath()` method to make sure that all special characters within the path are encoded.

Comment: Here is the URL after endcoding, `xyz%3D123%3Bxyz%3B` from my soap testing tool.

Comment: @prakashb that's correct. I forgot to encode `=` character which is special as well as `;`

Comment: After encoding, path variable is still truncated to xyz=123

Comment: @Radek23445 what URL you got after encoding?